# How to do a Blob storage to API data transfer in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I'm doing a POC that taking data from a csv file which is inside the Blob storage and do some mappings or transformations and send it to a Rest API (POST). I used a Lookup and web activities for this. But we can't do any transformation with these two. I thought of doing transformation with a DataFlow Activity and save it to Blob again and used Lookup and Web activities to do the rest. I have two questions.

1. Is there any other way to do this Blob to API copy?
2. Does Web activity has 1 min of execution time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any other way to do this Blob to API copy?**

No, Data Factory doesn't support Rest API as Sink dataset. We only could get data from REST API and can not transfer data to it. Ref: [Azure Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview)
[image]

**Does Web activity has 1 min of execution time?**

Yes, REST endpoints that the web activity invokes must return a response of type JSON. The activity will timeout at 1 minute with an error if it does not receive a response from the endpoint.

Ref: [Web activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Leon :) appreciate your help.

Comment: "Data Factory doesn't support Rest API as Sink dataset" mean we can't post data to an API?

Comment: @Kasunk No, we can't.  Others post the request in Data Factory Feedback, no response for now. To see: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/37066564-add-rest-as-a-sink

Comment: but I was able to post data to an API using Web activity. Used the body section to pass the data what API end point expect. Data saved successfully.

Comment: Yes, even I used two web activities, Get and Post. I used Get output inside the Post web activity's body. It also working

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, with the web active could achieve that. But in Data flow, that's not supported. You will find that the dataset of REST icon is gray(not support).

Comment: Yes @Leon, we can't use it in Dataflow. Even we can get data from API inside a Data flow activity as per my knowledge. Thanks for your time and support :)

Comment: @Kasun You're welcome! I'm glad talking with you. Data Factory still needs improve.  Have a good day!

Comment: Hello @Kasun,  hope you're doing well. This is a follow up that do you have other concerns? If my answer couldn't satisfy you, you could post a new one and mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thanks you and have good weekend.